# How to do integration testing with spring and junit by scanning classpath instead of manually specifying classes to autowire?

Tags: java, spring, testing

I'm trying to do some sort of integration testing (not really full testing, only it's not  really unit testing either) on a service :

```
package foo;


@Component
public class FooService {}
```

And the corresponding test :

```
package foo;

@SpringBootTest
public FooTest {
   @Autowired FooService fooService;
}
```

Only when I try to test it says

```
No qualifying bean of type 'foo.FooService' available
```

I could add the class to `@SpringBootTest` like this :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {FooService.class})
```

But I don't want to manually select the classes I want to test. My application is much larger than the MWE, and I want to test without having to specify each class I am testing and their respective dependencies.

Is there anyway to tell spring to scan and autowire dependencies like it would outside of tests ?

Comment: Is the `FooService` annotated with `@Service` or any other bean stereotype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `@Service` annotaion to the FooService class

Comment: From the Service Javadoc: _This annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning._ In other words: it shouldn't make a difference if the service is implemented as a class rather than an implementation of an interface.

Comment: Honestly it's my MWE that didn't work properly, but by trying to make a more thorough simplification of my code, I found the underlying issue :)